# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol from MSVCRTD.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am new to C++ and still trying to learn it. I have some code i copied over from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019).

The thing is I follow the instructions very carefully, but still get errors even tough what I do, is exactly what they tell me to do, it doesn't work.

```
// HelloWindowsDesktop.cpp
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, Windows desktop!");

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
        // in the top left corner.
        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        // End application-specific layout section.

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors:

1st error:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int >__cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)  Learn1  >C:\Users\user\source\repos\Learn1\Learn1\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1

2nd error:

> Error  LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Learn1  >C:\Users\user\source\repos\Learn1\Debug\Learn1.exe 1

I suspect the second error follows after the first. So if the first is solved the second will be too.

Comment: What kind of project did you chose when you created the project?

Comment: Nathan's right: you're supplying WinMain and it's expecting to link in main. Note the instructions at the top of the file tell you to compile with `/D_WINDOWS` and if you selected 'Win32 Console App' for your project then you won't have `_WINDOWS`, you'll have `_CONSOLE` or similar. You can probably just change this in your project settings, probably under the preprocessor tab.

Answer (score 4):

/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) is for console based applications. You should define `main` function in code.

/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) is for GUI applications. You should define `WinMain` function

You have selected the subsytem as CONSOLE and should be WINDOWS since you have WinMain and message handler.

You can change it under project properties

```
Project>Properties>Linker>System>Subsystem
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you ever got an answer, or if you even still need it, but I had this same error and it turned out that it was because I hadn't included an 'int main() {}' function. Hope this helps someone in the future because I had a lot of trouble finding the solution.

Comment: The other answer here did answer the question correctly: this program is using WinMain not main and so needed to be compiled with /subsystem:windows, which looks for WinMain not main.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this error, not sure your issue is the same as mine. I know what happened in my scenario, I want to generate a DLL file on the x86 platform, but I did not change the configuration correctly. the solution is right click project->propeties->Configuratioin General->modify Platform and Configuration Type(position is like below picture).
[image]